# oracle clear session in LOOP

Tags: oracle, plsql

I,ve a very strange situation. I don't know how to solve.  There exists not mine package,let's call him XXPACK, and I must call this  package's procedure in loop over table(Assume name is xxtable).

Situation is that 
if I run following script twice (where rowum<=150 means 300 records)

```
begin
for rec in (select * from xxtable where rownum<=150)
  LOOP
     XXPACK.XXPROC(rec.somecolumn);
  END LOOP;
end;
```

It works succesfully, but when I running once (where rownum<=300 means 300 records)

```
begin
for rec in (select * from xxtable where rownum<=300)
  LOOP
     XXPACK.XXPROC(rec.somecolumn);
  END LOOP;
end;
```

It's gives me some error about can't update some table. I think it blocks some tables or something like this. I need call procedure over all table, I tried use `some dmbs_lock.sleep(), dbms_session.reset_package(), pragma autonomous_transaction` not helped. I think if I fully clear session details in loop it will not cause error. How I can solve this situation?

Comment: "Some error"???

Comment: I think If will give exact error,it will not help to understand

Comment: Try us? Obviously if it is an error you are raising yourself using `raise_application_error` then only you will know what it means. But if it is an Oracle error message we might.

Comment: what is the total rowcount of your table.

Comment: total row count approximately 60000

Comment: @KamilIbadov may you have a problem of improperly sized-PGA?

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan I,ve no oracle administration skills well yet, I will learn about sized-PGA

Comment: `I think If will give exact error,it will not help to understand` Is there any issue sharing exact issue here ?

Comment: In Package  ig gives error "AC-UPD01" custom error, it looks script can't update "ACCOUNT" , it wrapped, and I can't uwnrap it and look the exact reason

Comment: Unfortunately , if the package is wrapped and you can't see the details there's **nothing we can do** . It's a piece of bespoke functionality, so the best we can do is make a few guesses. You need to get hold of the source code. Without that you're snookered.

Comment: may be i more loop I reach cursor limit or something like this?

Comment: Perhaps the procedure is choking on some value of `xxtable.somecolumn` that only occurs after the first 150 rows. If you capture the values being passed, you might see a pattern.